# Hidden Documents folder after turning off iCloud Drive

Tags: dropbox, macos, icloud

I recently tried iCloud Drive for syncing my `Desktop` and `Documents` folders. However, `Documents` was already being synced via Dropbox and I noticed that iCloud Drive and Dropbox don't get along. Seemingly random files inside `Documents` were copied over and over again for some reason.

So I decided to revert back to Dropbox and turn off iCloud sync. That worked fine on my iMac. However, doing the exact same thing on my MacBook Air made the Documents folder disappear. I quickly realized that it is only hidden (see screenshot), albeit without a preceding dot (`.`). I'm now struggling to unhide this folder. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run this in Terminal:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Documents
```